# Google App Engine: while saving an entity that has reference properties, is it the app's responsibility to maintain referential integrity?

Tags: google-app-engine

while saving an entity that has reference properties, is it the app's responsibility to check that the entities referred to by the reference properties already exist in the datastore? While unit testing with the datastore_v3_stub, I find that app engine will happily save a entity A that has a reference property B associated with it (and B does not exist in the datastore yet). further when A is saved, B is not saved. 
When you subsequently fetch A from the datastore, and try to navigate to B, you get an exception.
Is this expected behavior?

Example code:

```
user = MyUser(key_name='2',
            name='my user 2')
        e = db.get(user.key())
        self.assertTrue(e is None) # user does not exist in datastore yet
        preferences = Preferences(user=user) # user is a ReferenceProperty
       preferences.put()
        e = db.get(user.key())
        self.assertTrue(e is None) # user still does not exist in datastore
        e = db.get(preferences.key())
        self.assertFalse(e is None) # but preferences were still stored
e.user will give exception
```

EDIT: I am a python newbie, but is it possible to write a class that subclasses db.Model and overrides the put method to enforce referential integrity (by using some kind of reflection) before calling put of db.Model. Then I can just subclass this class to enforce referential integrity on my model classes (A, B above for example)

this is what i came up with. can any gurus code-review this:

```
for name, property in obj.properties().items():
            if isinstance(property, db.ReferenceProperty):
                try:
                    value = getattr(essay, name)
                except datastore_errors.Error:
                    print name, property, 'does not exist in datastore yet'
                    continue
                key = value.key()
                o = db.get(key)
                if o is None:
                    print name, property, value, 'does not exist in datastore yet'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is the responsibility of the app.

To quote:

> As with a Key value, it is possible for a reference property value to refer to a data entity that does not exist. If a referenced entity is deleted from the datastore, references to the entity are not updated. Accessing an entity that does not exist raises a ReferencePropertyResolveError.

taken from [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty)

Comment: also to note: A model instance can be assigned to a ReferenceProperty directly, and its key will be used. The ReferenceProperty value can be used as if it were a model instance, and the datastore entity will be fetched and the model instance created when it is first used in this way. Untouched reference properties do not query for unneeded data